# how to make spaces in command line by url link

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to make space to be like this  link   [http://www.teledunet.com/?channel=mbc 2](http://www.teledunet.com/?channel=mbc%202)

and this is my code

```
if %X% EQU 2 start http://www.teledunet.com/?channel=mbc%202
```

my problem is the space doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape % symbols in batch by doubling them. Use
`if %X% EQU 2 start http://www.teledunet.com/?channel=mbc%%202`